# Angular ng-show

Tags: html, angular.js

Is there any easier/shorter/better way to do the marked part?

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1exfADbszq8VSJ9BmBX8?p=preview)

```
<body ng-app="">
  Apple <input type="checkbox" ng-model="apple" aria-label="Toggle ngHide"><br/>
  Banana  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="banana" aria-label="Toggle ngHide"><br/>
<div>
  <!-- This part-->
  <div ng-show="apple || banana">
    You want to buy:
    <span> 
        <span ng-show="apple">Apple</span>
        <span ng-show="banana">Banana</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <!-- This part-->
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better and more performance oriented solution will be to use ng-if instead of ng-show. Although it doesn't matter with such few items on scope but with huge/big data its better to use ng-if.

```
<body ng-app="">
  Apple <input type="checkbox" ng-model="apple" aria-label="Toggle ngHide"><br/>
  Banana  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="banana" aria-label="Toggle ngHide"><br/>
<div>
  <div ng-if="apple || banana">
    You want to buy:
    <span> 
        <span ng-if="apple">Apple</span>
        <span ng-if="banana">Banana</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I was thinking more syntactically if you could make it shorter